# How to dynamically change the filter in a pandas data with subgroups of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns ( company, market_capitalization and debt_ratio). I want to get statistics of debt_ratio based on subgroups of market_capitalization.

I created a function 'subgroups_creation( column , n )' where column is the column that I'm grouping, market_capitalization, and n is the number of subgroups that I want to create. The function take range of the column and divide it into equally sized subgroups. The result is a dictionary that looks like the below.

```
Sub-Group  market_capitalization
1          :300
2          :639
3          :979
```

So, for example I want to know the mean of the debt_ratio of the companies that have a market_capitalization between 300 and 639 millions. Although I know how to filter by specific values and how to get the statistics after that, for research purposes I'm going to be changing the number of subgroups constantly, so I want these filters to dynamically update as a change the number of subgroups.

the result would be  number of subgroup = 5

```
Subgroup  market_capitalization     mean debt_ration
  1             300-638              0.25
  2             639-978              0.32
```

number of subgroup = 7

```
Subgroup  market_capitalization     mean debt_ration
  1             300-541              0.21
  2             542-785              0.40
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dummy data:

```
In [275]: df = pd.DataFrame({'company': list('abcdefg'), 
                             'market_cap': np.linspace(100, 500, 7), 
                             'debt_ratio': [.85,.34,.05,.34,.46,.234,.34]})
```

I'm not 100% clear on your question, but I think you may want the pandas `cut` function, which bins data into groups.  The code below cuts the data into 3 groups based on market_cap, groups, and calculates the average debt ratio.

```
In [282]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df['market_cap'], 3))['debt_ratio'].mean()
Out[282]: 
market_cap
(99.6, 233.333]       0.413333
(233.333, 366.667]    0.400000
(366.667, 500]        0.287000
Name: debt_ratio, dtype: float64
```

To have different numbers of groups, just pass a different parameter to cut.

```
In [283]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df['market_cap'], 5))['debt_ratio'].mean()
Out[283]: 
market_cap
(99.6, 180]    0.595
(180, 260]     0.050
(260, 340]     0.340
(340, 420]     0.460
(420, 500]     0.287
Name: debt_ratio, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, thanks. However, as you say, I did not formulate my question properly. I'm getting the point descriptor but my ultimate goal was to plot multiple box plots on one figure. Each box plot on the graph would represent the statistics of the debt_ratio of the companies grouped by market_cap.  Now I'm getting a point, I need all the values in order to be able to plot the box-plots. How can I achieve this? Thanks.